# Detect table within table in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

When using python-docx Table objects, is there a way to distinguish between a table that is within a cell of another table, to a plain "independent" table?

Comment: It depends. Say more about what you're trying to accomplish, like what the situation is and what the objective is from there.

Comment: I'm iterating over all tables in a document, but in some of my inputs there is a table inside a cell of another table and I need to ignore the inner one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property on a `docx.table.Table` object that will tell you whether it is nested within another table, but you can *find* tables that are in other tables like this:

```
def iter_tables_within_table(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for nested_table in cell.tables:
                yield nested_table
                yield from iter_tables_with_table(nested_table)

for nested_table in iter_tables_with_table(table):
    print("found a nested table %s" % nested_table)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to compare table objects? so that I could run first in your systems to find all nested tables and then run over all tables and discard the ones that are equal to a previously found nested table?

Comment: Two `Table` objects refer to the same table when `table_1._tbl == table_2._tbl`.